# Why is my code not sending/receiving the correct amount from shared memory?

Tags: c

Shared memory segment is of type char* by the way.

My sender, reads in a file and copys it onto the shared memory address current_channel.data:

```
char data[GLOB_SEGSIZE];
char filesize[21];
batch_read = 0, start_point = 0;
while ((int)(batch_read = pread(fd, data, GLOB_SEGSIZE, start_point)) > 0)
{
    sem_wait(current_channel.writer_sem);
   
    strncpy(current_channel.data, data, (size_t)GLOB_SEGSIZE);
    start_point += batch_read;
    printf("%zu of %s\n", strlen(data), filesize);
    
    sem_post(current_channel.reader_sem);
}
```

And my receiver, which waits for data to be written to the shared memory then uses it:

```
int curr_received = 0;
size_t filesize; // File size is received in the shared mem before the file transfer begins
while (curr_received < (int)filesize)
{
    sem_wait(current_channel.reader_sem);

    curr_received += strlen(current_channel.data);
    gfs_send(ctx, current_channel.data, strlen(current_channel.data));
    printf("%zu of %zu\n", strlen(current_channel.data), filesize);

    sem_post(current_channel.writer_sem);
}
```

In a nutshell, all the extraneous variables (everything not related to the size of the data on shared memory) are tested and correct. I am just having some issues getting the size of the data put in the shared memory. I notice when I print strlen(data) in the sender, I get a value that is much smaller than batch_read. I am just confused about how I would fix this error?

Comment: `I get a value that is much smaller than batch_read` - note that you're not actually printing out `batch_read` in the writer but `strlen(data)`.

Comment: Yeah, I printed out batch_read just prior. The batch_read value should be equal to strlen(data), just not sure why it is not.

Comment: Basically, what I read from the file (batch_read size) should be sent to the receiver. When I pick up what is sent within the receiver, then try to find the length of the data that was just sent over, it is way smaller than batch_read, which makes no sense. I noticed that the size of the data in the sender, before even sending it, is way smaller than batch_read. I think it is a strlen problem but have no idea how to find the size otherwise. Worst case I have to code it into the request somehow

Comment: `printf("%ld of %s\n", strlen(data), filesize);` The correct format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu` and `filesize` doesn't seem to be a pointer to a string at all.

Comment: `strncpy(current_channel.data, data, (size_t)GLOB_SEGSIZE);` `data` seems to be a local variable. That means you cannot rely on it being initialized with 0. `pread` does not handle strings but just bytestreams. You must add nul-termination before you feed that `data` into a string function. Also, `strncpy` does not add a 0 byte if the string is as long as the provided length limit

Comment: If your data contain any null bytes, then `strlen(data)` will differ from `batch_read`.  AND `strncpy()` will not copy all the data, but will instead pad the tail of the destination buffer after the first null byte with more null bytes.

Comment: Are you only sharing a string in that memory location? Otherwise "The batch_read value should be equal to strlen(data)" is not justified at all.

Comment: Okay, I updated my print statements to use %zu as opposed to %ld. I also updated the code I provided to show what var type filesize is exactly for each sender and receiver. My shared memory location solely holds a char*, so it is solely a string.

Regarding strncpy, should I just not use it? I can read less data from pread (subtract 1 from the size provided) and then add a null terminator. But it does seem there are already null terminators in my file being read

Comment: I might just try sending the size read into the shared memory, then reading that whole size after a delimiter of some sort. This way I do not need to do string stuff. I need to avoid strncpy it sounds like though, maybe just use memcpy?

Comment: Using `strncpy` to copy strings is not reliable. Instead, do `snprintf` or  truncate + `strncat` or your own loop or something.

Comment: Instead of using string functions, use memory functions like `memcpy()`. You can write the size of the buffer at the beginning of the shared memory.

Comment: That you point to the shared memory with a `char *` does not make its contents a string, or make the string functions appropriate for working with the contents.  That's a function of the contents.

Comment: However, that you emphasize that the shared memory contains only the data you are trying to exchange begs the question of whether your semaphores are doing what you want them to do. They evidently are not in the shared memory. If you are using named semaphores then they may be fine, but if you are using unnamed ones then possibly not, depending on how you initialized them.